# Unnamed: 0" column impossible to erase

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello I have a code that filters some rows of a csv and creates a csv without those rows but when I create that csv I get a column called "Unnamed: 0" and it is impossible to delete it.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
df.drop(df[df['Stock'].eq('No')].index, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('pedro.csv', index=False )
```

I have tried everything, I have even set index = False but it still comes out.

And I have also tried using drop

```
import pandas as pd

df2= pd.read_csv("pedro.csv")
df2.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
```

But it still doesn't work because it returns this:

```
   Unnamed: 0                                  Titulo        Precio Stock Ultima Vez
0           0  RPi CM4 - 8GB RAM, 32GB MMC, With Wifi  (EUR) 120.52   Yes  20-Nov-22
1           1      RPi CM4 - 2GB RAM, No MMC, No Wifi   (EUR) 44.40   Yes  20-Nov-22
2           2    RPi CM4 - 1GB RAM, 32GB MMC, No Wifi   (EUR) 57.08   Yes  20-Nov-22
3           3    RPi CM4 - 1GB RAM, 16GB MMC, No Wifi   (EUR) 50.74   Yes  20-Nov-22
4           4     RPi CM4 - 1GB RAM, 8GB MMC, No Wifi  (PLN) 279.00   Yes  20-Nov-22
```

Comment: Don't read the column in the first place, leave it as index: `df2 = pd.read_csv("pedro.csv", index_col=0)`

Comment: @mozway now return me this: `KeyError: "['Unnamed: 0'] not found in axis"`

Comment: Well, you don't need to `drop` now.

Comment: @mozway 
that doesn't work it keeps returning me to the column Unnamed: 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to reassign your dataframe after using [**`pandas.DataFrame.drop`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) or set `inplace=True.`

Try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")
df.drop(df[df['Stock'].eq('No')].index, inplace=True)
df.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1, inplace=True)
df.to_csv('pedro.csv', index=False)
```

Or this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("table.csv")

(
    df
     .loc[df['Stock'].ne('No'),
          ~df.columns.str.contains('^Unnamed')]
     .to_csv('pedro.csv', index=False)
)
```